# How to Access a Global Variable through TypeScript in a Browser Extension Context (and partially type it if possible)

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser-extension

### 1. The Problem

I'm trying to access a global variable from a website — [random OGS Example](https://online-go.com/review/557828) — through TypeScript in order to get data from the current board game.

I'm pretty new to TS so I'm not really sure how I would type this variable either. [The global variable itself was originally created in TS actually](https://github.com/online-go/goban/blob/master/src/GobanCanvas.ts), but it has a bazillion methods and properties, since there are so many functionalities. So, if I'm going to type it myself, I would rather only type what I need, if that's possible, or somehow import it from a package somewhere — I don't think the author has published it publicly anywhere.

In parallel to all this, there's also the question of whether or not global variables are available by default to browser extensions, [which might not be the case](https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/0900b7e92628668f766f637cec8fa822).

### 2. What I've Been Trying

So, what I've been trying (I've tried a million other variations...) to do is something like* — inside `content.ts`, which is run when inside the [OGS](https://online-go.com) domain —:

```
interface Goban {
  bounded_height: number;
}

declare var goban: Goban;

goban = window["global_goban"];

console.log(goban.bounded_height.toString());
```

The error I usually get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: goban is not defined
```

So what am I missing? Do I have to create a declaration file (`.d.ts`)? What is the proper way of dealing with this sort of import of a global variable from 3rd party code?

<sub>*: Depending on how you're trying to deal with the `window` object, you might have to add `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` to your `tsconfig.json` in order to have TS not complaining statically.</sub>

### 3. How to Fully Reproduce My Problem

For those unfamiliar with how to develop browser extensions, the simplest way to start, in TS, is to:

1. Create a simple `manifest.json`, for example:

   ```json
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "Name",
       "version": "0.0.2",
       "description": "Description.",
       "content_scripts": [
           {
               "matches": ["*://*.online-go.com/*"],
               "js": ["content.js"]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Create a `content.ts` file, with the code from the previous section.
3. Compile to JS with `tsc`.
4. Import the `manifest.json` and the `content.js` into a browser as an unpacked browser extension.
5. Load a [random OGS game](https://online-go.com/review/557828) and inspect it.

Comment: I've also tried [Using `eval` on content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts), but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. The Gist of It

Content scripts can't access global variables directly, they work in an "isolated world". From the [Content Script Environment MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Content_script_environment):

> However, content scripts get a "clean" view of the DOM. This means:
>
> - Content scripts cannot see JavaScript variables defined by page scripts.

But you can still work around it by sharing resources through the `web_accessible_resources` key in your `manifest.json`.

### 2. One Possible Workaround

Here is one way how this could be done:

`manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Description.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.online-go.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"]
}
```

You can add whichever script you might need to the `web_accessible_resources` key, just like the ones used in the `matches` key above for example. You can also use [wildcards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns), like `*`, to match several at the same time.

> You might still need to add this to your `compilerOptions` inside your `tsconfig.json`: `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true`.

`script.ts`:

```
interface Goban {
  bounded_height: number;
}

declare var goban: Goban;

goban = window['global_goban'];

console.log(goban.bounded_height.toString());
```

`content.ts`:

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
document.head.append(script);
```

You might also need to install `@types/chrome` through, for example, `npm i --save @types/chrome`.

### 3. Further Resources

Also, content scripts can communicate with page scripts using `window.postMessage` and `window.addEventListener`.

Further resources:

- [Communicating with the web page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_the_web_page)
- [`web_accessible_resources` MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources)

Comment: You might also need to install `@types/chrome`.

Comment: In your example, if I try to do `console.log(goban.bounded_height.toString() + "from content.ts");` inside `content.ts`, I'm still getting `goban is undefined`. From what I can guess, in every TS file I wish to use this global variable, I'll have to add it to `web_accessible_resources`?

Comment: Your answer is very close to what I want, the only "but" is the stuff in the previous comment. But could you also add a link to documentation (MDN preferably) with scope information about `content.js` et al.?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to add them to `web_accessible_resources` (you can use wildcards: [Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources))

Answer (score -1):

If you open the console in your browser on online-go.com you can type in `goban` and see that it's globally available just like that. So, `window.goban` would be the way to access the variable. I would do something like:

```
interface Goban {
  bounded_height: number;
}

const local_goban: Goban = window.goban;

console.log(local_goban.bounded_height.toString());
```

or just

```
interface Goban {
  bounded_height: number;
}

const goban: Goban = window.goban;

console.log(goban.bounded_height.toString());
```

in your code you defined `global_goban` but then went on to access just `goban`. Make sure your variable names are consistent.

As far as typing the global variable from that page automatically, I don't think that is really possible. Typescript doesn't work in a browser, it always has to be compiled to normal JS, so you will just have to write in the types you want manually... you could check something like [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) but as you mention, if they haven't posted any public repositories with their code/package then you probably won't be able to find anything for that.

EDIT: to get typescript to not complain about the window variable, you might need to add something more like:

```
type Goban = {
  bounded_height: number;
}

declare global {
   var goban: Goban;
}
```

Read more about: [Declaring Global Variables](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript)

Comment: The `goban` thing was a kinda of a typo when I was copying the code from my editor. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is `window.goban` really working for you? TS gives me back the error: `Property 'goban' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.`.

Comment: `window.goban` is the correct way to access the variable... but, for typescript to not complain... you might want to checkout [this article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript)

Comment: Still not working over here (and I've also tried a bunch of variations from that article as well). TS won't complain statically anymore, but the variable is still undefined. Did it really work for you? I'm also starting to think that global variables are not available to browser extensions by default, see [this article](https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/0900b7e92628668f766f637cec8fa822) for example.